# Unresolved external symbol - RtlIpv6AddressToStringA

Tags: c, ip-address, ipv6

I want to convert an Ipv6 Adress to a String. But I always get the following error:

Unresolved external symbol "S__imp__RtlIpv6AddressToStringA@8" in Funktion "_main"."

```
RtlIpv6AddressToStringA(&cli_addr.sin6_addr, client_addr_buffer));
```

I added

```
#include <in6addr.h>
#include <ip2string.h>
```

I'm not sure what component is missing.

Comment: What if you try to use `RtlIpv6AddressToString()` in main? (Without the trailing `A`)

Comment: It shows the same error

Comment: Is this the only one error the compiler raises? Are there any previous errors/warnings you omitted? Is the compiler able to find "ip2string.h"? It would be better if you could include in your question a simple main application reproducing the issue: just a constant address, the function call and a printf to print the result.

Comment: [According to the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ip2string/nf-ip2string-rtlipv6addresstostringa), "The RtlIpv6AddressToString function is included in the Ntdll.lib import library included in the Windows Driver Kit (WDK)."